# What exactly was Charlie going to say before she got cut off by Maverick?

Tags: plot-explanation, top-gun

In *Top Gun* (1986), after he took down all enemy flighters in the midair and
got appreciation on the front page of every newspaper
in the English-speaking world, Maverick met by Charlie:

> Charlie: Hello, Pete Mitchell. I heard the best of the best were gonna
> be back here, **so...**
>
> Maverick: This could be complicated. You know, on the first one, I crashed and burned.

What exactly was Charlie going to say before she got cut off by Maverick?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few versions of the script, none of them I found are the final cut of the movie as released in theater or VHS or DVD (I have seen all three versions). At the end, there's music playing (Charlie picks one of Maverick's favourite in the jukebox) then they see each other and talk, with the lines of dialog you mention. In the [script](https://assets.scriptslug.com/live/pdf/scripts/top-gun-1986.pdf) I refer to, these are the lines found on the last page:

> CHARLIE : They gave me the big option. Anywhere. I checked around. Found out the best of the best were all gonna' be back here. So
> **I took Perry's job**.
>
> MAVERICK : This could be a complicated engagement.
>
> CHARLIE : I don't know. I've only done it twice.
>
> MAVERICK : How'd you do?
>
> CHARLIE : Crashed on the first one. I'll tell you tomorrow. But its looking good so far.

This (she leaves the words hanging) seems more (to me) of a dramatic-romantic part than her saying something as in the original script, because it goes back to their first meeting, in the bar (page 34).

> CHARLOTTE : how'd you do?
>
> MAVERICK (remembering) : Crashed and burned on the first one...
>
> CHARLOTTE (looking up) : ...and the second one?
>
> MAVERICK (wry smile) : I'll tell you tomorrow. But its looking
> good so far.